# How can I force the rendering of a form with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Good Morning,

I am currently building a classic todoList app with HTML5, CSS3 and JS in addition to using the Bootstrap 4.3.1 framework.
The drawback I have is that when I redraw the screen to test the responsive and I'm about to reach 768px wide, the "Add Item" button is compressed and the words are put on top of each other. As could be forced so that this does not happen and the button always have the words with the button with number "2".

[image]

On the other hand according to the configuration I have when the screen is reduced below 768px as seen in the second image, both the text box and the button are placed one below the other. As I could do so that when this happens a margin is generated between both to not be so stuck together as an edge margin so that they are not so stuck to the edge of the page.

[image]

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question?

Comment: @Ksav sorry for not add code to de cuestion. Do not take it into account, but correct this for my next consultations. Luckily I got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question on how to make the button take up full width of its content, you could use the [input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) component of Bootstrap 4. Specifically [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons) part.

[Here's a CodePen example.](https://codepen.io/emilcarlsson/pen/94b2732e8de968ac7ceb7d93ff03b4c5)

Alternatively you could change the class of your button next to the input from `col-md-2` to `col-md-auto`. Then you also have to change the class on your input, just remove the `-10`. Which would result in this:

```html
<form id="itemForm" class "row my-3">
  <input type="text" id="itemInput" class="col-md form-control" placeholder="Tarea...">
  <button class="btn btn-green col-md-auto" type="submit">Agregar Item</button>
</form>
```

---

The other problem is easily fixed by adding a [padding utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) to the `<div class="container-fluid">`. Like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
 ...
</div>
```

This adds a padding on the x-axis (left & right). The value ranges from 0-5.

Comment: thanks for your response, with this I managed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove row class from form

```
<form id="itemForm" class="my-3">
```